# Найти максимум функции методом золотого сечения C#

Tags: c#

Имеется код на шарпе, для вычисления минимума функции одной переменной. Необходимо его адаптировать под нахождение максимума функции.
Прикладываю непосредственно класс в котором непосредственно описана вся логика.
Подскажите, что именно здесь необходимо изменить, что бы адаптировать данный класс. Пробовала изменить сама, но успехом не увенчалось.

```
using System;
namespace ZolotoeSecheniye
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Класс для оптимизации одномерной функции методом золотого сечения
    /// </summary>
    public class Optimizer
    {
        private const double Phi = 1.61804d;
        private const int IntervalSearchIterations = 100;
        public int Iterations { get; set; }
        public Optimizer()
        {
            Iterations = 0;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Класс для представление отрезка, с точкой по середине
        /// </summary>
        private class Triple
        {
            public double A { get; set; }
            public double B { get; set; }
            public double C { get; set; }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "("+A+","+B+","+C+")";
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Функция для поиска минимума функции fotx
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fotx">Функция</param>
        /// <param name="x0">Старт поиска интервала поиска</param>
        /// <param name="h">Шаг и точность поиска</param>
        /// <returns>Минимум функции</returns>
        public double MinFunc(Func<double, double> fotx, double x0, double h)
        {
            double x0left = x0 - h;
            double x0right = x0 + h;
            bool isRightDirection = fotx(x0right) < fotx(x0left);
            return SearchMin(
                fotx,
                FindMinSearchInterval(fotx, x0, isRightDirection ? x0right : x0left),
                h
            ); 
        }
        private double SearchMin(Func<double, double> fotx, Tuple<double, double> searchInterval, double h)
        {
            Iterations++;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Количество итераций - " + Iterations);
            Tuple<double, double> newPoints = GetSearchPoints(searchInterval.Item1, searchInterval.Item2);
            Console.WriteLine("Интервал поиска решения - " + TupleToString(searchInterval));
            Console.WriteLine("Точки x1, x2: " + TupleToString(newPoints));
            Tuple<double, double> newCoords;
            if(fotx(newPoints.Item1) >= fotx(newPoints.Item2))
            {
                newCoords = new Tuple<double, double>(newPoints.Item1, searchInterval.Item2);
            }
            else
            {
                newCoords = new Tuple<double, double>(searchInterval.Item1, newPoints.Item2);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Обновленные концы интервала поиска - " + TupleToString(newCoords));
            //Console.WriteLine("Разница (A-C) - " + (newCoords.Item2 - newCoords.Item1));
            if(Math.Abs(newCoords.Item2 - newCoords.Item1) < h)
            {
                return (newCoords.Item1 + newCoords.Item2) / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                return SearchMin(fotx, newCoords, h);
            }
        }
        private Tuple<double, double> GetSearchPoints(double a, double b)
        {
            return new Tuple<double, double>(
                b - (b-a)/Phi,
                a + (b-a)/Phi
            );
        }
        private Tuple<double, double> FindMinSearchInterval(Func<double, double> fotx, double x0, double x1)
        {
            double a = x0, b = x1, c = CalcIntervalEnding(a, b);
            //Console.WriteLine("Ищем интервал поиска...");

            for (int i = 0; i < IntervalSearchIterations; i++)
            {
                bool isLuckyTriple = fotx(a) > fotx(b) && fotx(c) > fotx(b);

                if (isLuckyTriple)
                    break;

                a = b;
                b = c;
                c = CalcIntervalEnding(a, b);
            }
            Triple returning = new Triple()
            {
                A = a,
                B = b,
                C = c
            };
            //Console.WriteLine("Найден интервал поиска. Удачаная золотая тройка - " + returning);
            return new Tuple<double, double>(returning.A, returning.C);
        }
        private String TupleToString(Tuple<double, double> tuple)
        {
            return "(" + tuple.Item1 + "," + tuple.Item2 + ")";
        }
        private double CalcIntervalEnding(double a, double b)
        {
            return (a * (1/Phi) - b) / ((1/Phi) - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Хмм какой то замудрённый код. На [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Метод_золотого_сечения#.D0.A4.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F) расписан алгоритм. И на втором шаге в скобочках написано (_для поиска max изменить неравенство на y1 <= y2_). Я у вас нашел похожую строчку `if(fotx(newPoints.Item1) >= fotx(newPoints.Item2))`.

Comment: Пробовала ранее, смотрела там статью, не вышло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public double MaxFunc(Func<double, double> fotx, double x0, double h)
{
  return MinFunc((a) => -fotx(a), x0, h);
}
```

Comment: Добавила, ругается на строчку - return MinFunc((a, b) => -fotx(a, b), x0, h); "Делегат "Func<double, double> не принимает аргументы 2."

Comment: @Лидия `-fotx(a, b)` - этого нет уже в ответе, наверное автор его исправил.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!